# Typo3 QueryBuilder as LIKE search with dynamic parameter

Tags: typo3, sql-like, query-builder

Using Typo3 QueryBuilder as LIKE search with dynamic parameter does not work.
If I replace the variable with a static string than I get the expected result

```
public function getAutocompleteData($query)
{
    $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('tx_kesearch_index');

    $queryBuilder->select('title')
        ->from('tx_kesearch_index')
        ->where(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->like(
                'title',
                $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('%' . $queryBuilder->escapeLikeWildcards($query)) // 'test' works
            )
        );


    debug($queryBuilder->getSQL());
    $data = $queryBuilder->execute();
  
    return $data->fetchAll();
}
```

[image]
What makes here the difference? How should be used correctly with dynamic values?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because auf the missing `%` at the end:

`$queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('%' . $queryBuilder->escapeLikeWildcards($query) . '%')`

Comment: thanks for the feedback it does not seems to work I attached a screenshot on debug. I think is because of the quotes